# Generating a self-signed cert with dockerfile not actually generating a self-signed cert

Tags: docker, openssl, dockerfile

First, I'm fairly new to docker. But this seems pretty straight forward.

I am working off of [this dockerfile](https://github.com/getgrav/docker-grav/blob/master/Dockerfile). I made some very basic modifications like installing openssl and generating some self-signed certs so I can use ssl in apache. Here is a section that I added to the linked dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /ssl-certs
RUN openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj \
    "/C=../ST=../L=..../O=LAB/CN=....." \
    -keyout /ssl-certs/ssl.key -out /ssl-certs/ssl.crt

RUN mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl/
COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
```

However, when I compile this I get the following output:

```
 => CACHED [ 8/19] RUN openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj     "/C=../ST=../L=....  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/19] RUN mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl/                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [10/19] COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [11/19] COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt                                                 0.0s
------
 > [10/19] COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key:
------
------
 > [11/19] COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt:
------
```

This basically tells me openssl isn't actually doing anything or docker doesn't wait for openssl to finish which doesn't seem likely. I've looked around and I can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COPY /ssl-certs/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
COPY /ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
```

The COPY command tries to access `/ssl-certs` on the host, not inside the container. You may try

```
RUN cp /ssl-certs/ssl.key /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key \
 && cp /ssl.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
```

Edit: regardless that I consider as a bad practice to

- build secrets (private key) into the container, rather mount the secrets at run-time
- create non-deterministic builds (generating a new random private key)

I guess or rather hope it's for dev/education purpose, but when doing ssl, let's do it properly, even for the self-signed certificates

Comment: > build secrets (private key) into the container, rather mount the secrets at run-time
Are you saying to mounting a location outside of the container is good practice?

>create non-deterministic builds (generating a new random private key)
Yeah, this is just a dev/education thing. Trying to learn docker. Focusing on making things work then go back and make it work properly. Always worked best for me.

Comment: @Mailstorm `mounting a location outside of the container is good practice?` I'd say it's better. For secrets (or other parameters) you can mount, pass as env variables or fetch from the script/code.